# (Script) Latest Git for Windows using PowerShell or cmd?

Tags: windows, git, powershell, batch-file, git-for-windows

How to download latest `Git for Windows` using *cmd* or *powershell* ? (or other built-in windows software)

Currently, i have a script to check if Windows is `x32 or x64` :

```
# eq is equal
# ne is not equal
if ((gwmi win32_operatingsystem | select osarchitecture).osarchitecture -ne "64-bit")
{
    #32 bit logic here
    Write "32-bit OS"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
}
else
{
    #64 bit logic here
    Write "64-bit OS"
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue."
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would be to use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) on the target machine. After chocolatey is installed a simple:

```
choco install git
```

downloads and installs git for windows. Check [the package site](https://chocolatey.org/packages/git) first, if the latest version has been packaged. It might sometimes take a couple of days after the release of a new version before that happens.

---

If you are looking for a manual way to download the latest release from github, you can use the github api.

First figure out the name of the asset, that you want to download. They are listed here : https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest. The assets you are interested in look like this:

```
Git-2.25.1-64-bit.exe
Git-<version>-<architecture>.exe
```

Now get the page you were just looking at as a json object. The github api does that for you: https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest

Finally find your asset in there and pass the download link to `Invoke-WebRequest`.

```bsh
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$architecture = '64-bit'
$assetName = "Git-*-$architecture.exe"

$gitHubApi = 'https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest'
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $gitHubApi -UseBasicParsing
$json = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
$release = $json.assets | Where-Object Name -like $assetName

Invoke-WebRequest $release.browser_download_url -OutFile ".\$($release.name)"
```

**Note**: Depending on the scale on which you want to use this, you should know that the github api allows only 60 calls per hour, if you are an unauthenticated user: https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting

Comment: Using chocolatey works, but can git be downloaded without any 3rd party software? :D

Comment: @WinScriptDev that is precisely what the second half of my answer is about. Did it not work for you?

Comment: Sadly,... no :(

Comment: What exactly did not work? Please provide the exception that you see. What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: I use PowerShell 5.1. I first tested the script as admin in PowerShell ISE (x64) and i saw that appeared that script is downloading something, but not the latest git release

Comment: `".\$($release.name)"` will download a file named `Git-2.25.1-64-bit.exe` and save it to whatever path your ISE shows in the console when running the code. If you opened ISE as a normal user, pasted the code in and hit `F5` the file will be in your user folder. Can you please verify that this file can't be found on your system? I tested the script with your setup. Works fine here.

Comment: But can this script run on older ps versions? (like 2.0)

Comment: No. There is no `Invoke-WebRequest` in 2.0. Btw: Nothing in your question indicates that compatibility with 2.0 is a requirement.

Comment: Its ok. I have a script to upgrade from any powershell versions to powersehll 5,

Comment: But it is possible to automatically replace ```$architecture = 64-bit``` with the detected os architecture?

Comment: Yes that is possible, but please don't make up additional requirements as you go. Your question was, how the latest version of git for windows can be downloaded using PowerShell. My answer addresses this question. Please keep in mind that so also has a search function. Many basic questions like "how do I figure out the cpu architecture in PowerShell?" have been asked and answered before.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this! And thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: Please klick "accept answer" if you feel, that your question was answered.

Comment: Actually, when i tested this script in windows 7 , the following errors appears: ```Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.``` ; ```ConvertFrom-Json : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.``` and
```Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Uri'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an 
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again```

Comment: For automatic JSON conversion... Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://api.github.com/repos/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest'